# What is the right way to check a input form field value(empty and null..) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some input filed into a form. I am trying to check the empty and null of those value.

My js code as:

```
$(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(){
 var cid = $('#CTID').val();
 var sid = $('#sbj').val();
 var d = $('#bdate').val();
 var t = $('#time').val();
 var dt = d+' '+t;
 var path = '/admin/exam_schedule';
 if (cid ==''||cid==null || sid==''||cid==null || d==''||d==null || t==''||t==null) {
    alert('Input all data fields');
 }
 else{
     var url='/admin/insert_exam_schedule';
    $.post(url,{c:cid,s:sid,d:dt},function(data){
       alert(data);
       window.location.href= path
    });
 }
  });
});
```

But the problem of this code are: When I give space into the input field then it takes the space as input.But, I want to validate all of the possible way, so that I can take real data as input.

Comment: Also same problem using input.length @user000000000

Comment: you may use trim, like cid.trim()

Comment: You also likely want to change `$('#submit').click(function(){` to `$('#submit').on("click",function(e){ e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try,

```
var condition = $('#CTID,#sbj,#bdate,#time').map(function(){
  return $.trim(this.value);
}).get().join('') === '';

if(condition){ alert('Input all data fields'); }
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MWe7b/)

Improvised version,

```
var condition = false;

$('#CTID,#sbj,#bdate,#time').each(function(){
  if($.trim(this.value) === "") {
    condition = true;
    return false;
  }
})

if(condition){ alert('Input all data fields'); }
```

Full code would be,

```
 $('#submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefalut();

   var condition = $('#CTID,#sbj,#bdate,#time').map(function(){
     return $.trim(this.value);
   }).get().join('') === '';

   if(condition){ alert('Input all data fields'); }
   else {
           var url='/admin/insert_exam_schedule';
           $.post(url,{c:cid,s:sid,d:dt},function(data){
            alert(data);
            window.location.href= path
           }); 
    }
 });
```

Comment: There may be some thing wrong. It takes empty values.

Comment: @NonZero *May be some thing wrong* have you used `e.preventDefault()` as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465733/what-is-the-right-way-to-check-a-input-form-field-valueempty-and-null-using#comment37863957_24465733

Comment: Given you are iterating each item anyway, it would probably be more efficient to use `each` and have a flag which indicates whether one field is empty rather than go through each item and then subsequently join them into one large string.

Answer (score 1):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) will only return `null` for a `select` element, everything else should return `''`, therefore, if you aren't using a `select` element then `str != ''` or `str.length > 0` should be sufficient.

If you are using  a `select` element then you check whethre the value is assigned first e.g. `str && str != ''` or `str && str.length > 0` (or alternatively you default `null` to `''` for consistency).

If you want to exclude whitespace-only strings then use [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) during validation.

```
var cid = $('#CTID').val();
var sid = $('#sbj').val();
var d = $('#bdate').val();
var t = $('#time').val();
var dt = d+' '+t;
if (cid.trim() == '' || sid.trim() == '' || d.trim() == '' || t.trim() == '') {
    // data invalid
}
else {
    // data valid
}
```

Comment: "When I give space into the input field then it takes the space as input" - i think OP wants to trim the input as well...

Comment: But,According to your answer it will works when the t value is not set. Because you are checking only dt.  

It will works, When you will change the if condiction as

if (cid.trim() == '' || sid.trim() == '' || d.trim() == ''|| t.trim() == '') {
        // data invalid
    }